# TinkerPop3 - Finding the same properties between edge

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm trying to output vertices's that had a same edge properties (weight:0.4) from the created in the modern graph.

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to get the list of vertices that has at least one outgoing "created" edge with a "weight" value of "0.4":

```
gremlin> g.V().filter(outE('created').has('weight',0.4d))
==>v[1]
==>v[4]
```

Comment: This one worked for me, thanks. I just added .values('name') and the result exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very limited example. I am guessing you are asking how to create and query edge properties. If that is so, here is an example of creating an edge with properties:

```
graph = TinkerFactory.createModern();
v1 = graph.addVertex();
v2 = graph.addVertex();
e = v1.addEdge("LABEL", v2);
e.property("weight", "0.4");
```

Then querying for an edge with that property:

```
graph.traversal().E().has("weight", "0.4").toList();
```

Comment: I think the question means that the user needs vertices having edges with the 'created' edge label and weight of 0.4